# Partial Successful Action behaviour

Tags: user-expectation, bulk

I'm building an app where a user might perform bulk-acceptance on items (for example - shifts he's eligible to work in). Now when the request reaches backend some items has expired.

I can think of showing this info in 2 ways :

1. Accept eligible items and show error message to user about in-eligible items(remove them from UI).
2. Ask user to refresh and sync up latest eligible items to perform action on.

Comment: please post your work so far.

Comment: Hi Neha, can you please share some more details about the context in question? What causes the items to expire? Why would the user require to manually sync up the latest eligible items? Can an AJAX call keep updating the table with the latest items so that the items never expire?

Answer (score 2):

When people make bulk selections it is possible that they make dicisions based on multiple items. When just part of the items can be accepted they might want to change a few considerations. For that reason don't just save the set when it can't be saved exactly as the user requested. **Let them review it first before saving it again.**

But this come with another problem: There will be no guarantee that the next save action will succeed, non-expired items can still expire. And after that it can still be unsuccesful etc. etc.

A solution is how buying concert tickets works at some online ticket shops. Tickets are reserved as soon as the customer puts them in the shopping basket. This reservation expires after some time so others get a chance to buy the tickets when the current customer abandons the buying process. In your case you might want to reserve the eligible items (they will not expire for this user) and show what items did expire in the meanwhile. Let them review the selection and save it.

While the already chosen items can't expire, other items still can. You can reduce this friction by frequently check for updates of the same list, and when an item in the list expires show a label "expired" next to it.